# Within array of objects merge items by common key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking for a way to merge objects with the same date into one.
I'd appreciate your help.

```
const data = [
                { date: '1 Day', green: 35 },
                { date: '2 Day', green: 64 },
                { date: '3 Day', green: 46 },
                { date: '4 Day', green: 87 },
                { date: '5 Day', green: 32 },
                { date: '1 Day', red: 85 },
                { date: '2 Day', red: 55 },
                { date: '3 Day', red: 37 },
                { date: '1 Day', orange: 4 },
                { date: '2 Day', orange: 44 },
                { date: '3 Day', orange: 9 },
                { date: '4 Day', orange: 88 },
                { date: '5 Day', orange: 60 },
                { date: '6 Day', orange: 15 },
            ];
```

Desired output.

```
const data = [
                { date: '1 Day', green: 35, red: 85,  orange: 4 },
                { date: '2 Day', green: 64, red: 55,  orange: 44 },
                { date: '3 Day', green: 46, red: 37, orange: 9  },
                { date: '4 Day', green: 87, orange: 88 },
                { date: '5 Day', green: 32, orange: 60 },
                { date: '6 Day', orange: 15 },
            ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a hash to combine the different objects with the same `key` (date, in this case) using the `spread` operator, while iterating over the objects in the array

```js
// reusable function to reduce object arrays
// `key` - <String>; object property name to combine objects by
// `data` - <Array>, of objects
function reduceObjectArr(key, data) {
   const hash = []
   for (let el of data) {
      const keyValue= el[key]
      hash[keyValue] = { ...(hash[keyValue] || {} ), ...el }
   }

   return Object.values(hash)
}

// current usage
const data = [
    { date: '1 Day', green: 35, red: 85,  orange: 4 },
    { date: '2 Day', green: 64, red: 55,  orange: 44 },
    { date: '3 Day', green: 46, red: 37, orange: 9  },
    { date: '4 Day', green: 87, orange: 88 },
    { date: '5 Day', green: 32, orange: 60 },
    { date: '6 Day', orange: 15 },
]

const result = reduceObjectArr('date', data)
console.log(result)
```